# Use SELECT results as column name for parent SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-insert

I have a TMP_FOO table that has the same columns as FOO plus some more. I need to insert all the rows from TMP_FOO into FOO. I could write the following:

```
INSERT INTO FOO (SELECT bar, baz FROM TMP_FOO);
```

But I need it to be generic so that I only change the name of the tables. My best try:

```
INSERT INTO FOO
(SELECT 
  (SELECT column_name
  FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'FOO')
FROM
 f2020.TMP_FOO)
```

Which doesn't work because

```
SELECT column_name
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'FOO'
```

returns multiple rows. Can I archieve what I want in plain SQL (without needing to dynamically build the query string)?

Comment: No, you can't do that with static SQL. It will have to be dynamic - either actual dynamic SQL, or playing with client variables (e.g. SQL\*Plus substitution variables). [This might be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51305332/266304)?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I archieve what I want in plain SQL (without needing to dynamically build the query string)?

No.

In plain SQL, you cannot generate the list of output column from another query. The database needs to know which columns the query will return at the time when it parses the query (ie *before* the query is actually executed).

Answer (score 0):

You don't use columns `names` from the result, INSERT INTO table SELECT must keep same count of columns with destination table. I think, that is not possible create column list runtime. You must type all columns of FOO - as your first example:

```
INSERT INTO FOO (SELECT FOO_colname_1, FOO_colname_2, FOO_colname_3 FROM TMP_FOO);
```

and reverse, if FOO_TEMP has more columns you must add NULL or default values:

```
INSERT INTO TMP_FOO (SELECT TMP_FOO_colname_1, TMP_FOO_colname_2, TMP_FOO_colname_3, NULL, NULL FROM FOO);
```